# Every open set has a proper open subset. What spaces satisfy this property?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space satisfying the following property: every (nonempty) open set of $X$ has a (nonempty) proper open subset.

> Does this property have a name?
>
> What are some spaces with this property?
>
> What are some properties that imply this property (eg. Hausdorff, separable, second countable, etc.)?

The intuition is that, if you have an open set $U \subseteq X$, you can "zoom in" at any point of $U$, forever.

*Example.* If $X$ has the discrete topology, then it doesn't have this property, because singletons $\{x\} \subseteq X$ are open sets that *don't* have (nonempty) proper open subsets.

*Example.* If $X$ is ${\mathbb R}^n$ with the Euclidean topology, then it does have this property, because, for any open ball $B$ of radius $\epsilon$ around $x \in X$, you can take the open ball of radius $\epsilon/2$, which is a (nonempty) proper open subset of $B$.

Comment: Any space which has open sets who contain only finitely many elements can't have this property, as an extension of the argument for the discrete topology.

Comment: Also, any infinite space with a finite topology can't have this property.

Comment: As stated in the title, the Answer is "None" because the empty set is always open and has no proper subset. Clearly you meant "every non-empty open set".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The title is vague. The main text is more precise.

Comment: A $T_1$ space with no isolated points has no non-empty subset-minimal open sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not implied by a lot of your properties as a countable discrete space lacks it, but such a space *is* second countable Hausdorff, separable etc.

It implies some other properties: $X$ has infinitely many open sets, all of which are infinite. (if $X$ would have finitely many open sets, their (open!) intersection would be minimal; If $U$ is open non-empty, define $U_0 = U$ and $\emptyset \neq U_{n+1} \subsetneq U_n$ whenever $X$ has this property, and then $\cup_n (U_{n}\setminus U_{n+1})$  is an infinite subset of $U$, so $U$ is infinite.

Spaces that are dense in themselves (i.e. have no isolated points) and are also $T_0$ will have this property: if $U$ is open then $U$ is not a singleton, so we have $x,y \in X$ with $x \neq y$, By $T_0$-ness we find an open set $V$ containing $x$ but not $y$ (or reversely), and then $U \cap V$ is strictly smaller and open too.

Equivalently, if $X$ fails the condition, there is some minimal open subset $U$. If $U$ has one point this point is isolated. If it has more, the $T_0$ condition fails for points from this set. So your condition is implied by "$X$ is dense in itself and $T_0$".

As @bof remarked in the comments: if $X$ has the "no minimal open set property",  and $Y$ is any space whatsoever, then $X \times Y$ also obeys it ($O$ non-empty open in $X \times Y$ contains a basic non-empty open set $U \times V\subseteq O$ and $U$ is not minimal so $\emptyset \neq U' \subsetneq U$ open exists and then $U' \times V$ is smaller and non-empty open inside $O$ so $O$ is not minimal.)

Comment: Could be clearer. Of course "no point has a minimal open set containing it" is only a sufficient condition for "every nonempty open set has a nonempty open proper subset", but the casual reader might think you're saying it's a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: By the way, $T_0$ is just as good as $T_1$ here.

Comment: @bof sure, it's equivalent with $T_0$ added. I expanded.

Comment: The OP's condition is not equivalent to "$X$ is dense in itself and $T_0$" because it doesn't imply $T_0$. If $X$ has the OP's property, then $X\times Y$ also has the property, but $Y$ could have the "indiscrete" topology.